# How Do I Find And Replace String in Powershell

Tags: powershell

i Want Find All desired Characters in String And Replace Some Of Them...
Ex : "Facebook" Has It Two "o". But i Want Replace Last "o" Character
Examples : "Facebook" -> "Facebo0k"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the last occurrence of a specific character on a line, you can use a look ahead and an end of line anchor.

```
$str = "A line with the word facebook in it."

$str -Replace 'o(?=[^o]+$)','0'

A line with the word facebo0k in it.
```

Another example

```
$str = "A line with the word facebook and another word"

$str -Replace 'o(?=[^o]+$)','0'

A line with the word facebook and another w0rd
```

Here is my best explanation of this regex pattern.

- `$` End of line anchor.
- `(?=)` We are looking ahead. In this scenario we are really looking for the end of the line to make sure it's the last `o` in the line.
- `[^o]+` This says "not the character `o`, *1 or more times*." Since the `o` may not be the last character on the line, this covers any character between the target `o` and the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell has built in regex operators to use with strings, for example:

```
$String = "Facebook" 
$String -replace "oo","o0"
```

This code example will replace any instance of "oo" with "o0".

Comment: My Variable is User input and i Can't Forecast Input
Maybe Input is "HelloWorld" and i Want Replace Last "o".

Comment: Then you have a different question than what you asked.